# Scala mergeMsg with def

Tags: scala

I have to write a `mergeMsg` function.

The function should have the following signature

```
((String, String, Double), (String, String, Double)) => (String, String, Double)
```

In some way, every object of the former tuple should be added to the corresponding of the latter tuple.

How can I write this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do... Can you make an example with input and expected output?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is to use `Cats` and `Monoids`:

```
scala> import cats.implicits._
import cats.implicits._

scala> type Tup = (String, String, Double)
defined type alias Tup

scala> def mergeMsg(a: Tup, b: Tup): Tup = a |+| b 
mergeMsg: (a: Tup, b: Tup)Tup

scala> mergeMsg(("Hello", "World", 4.5), (" John", " Cup", 25.5))
res0: Tup = (Hello John,World Cup,30.0)
```

Of course, you don't need to define the type alias `Tup`, it just makes it a bit shorter.

Comment: +1 for `Monoid`! Just wanted to note that one could define a custom instance of `Monoid[String]` in order to concatenate using `" "` instead of the default behavior.

Comment: by the way, that's not even a Monoid, probably just a Semigroup is enough :)

Comment: Yeah, the space would break the identity law :)

Answer (score 0):

Not that flexible but without additional library dependencies:

```
  type Tpl[T, V] = (T, T, V)
  type Sum[T] = (T, T) => T

  def mergeMsg[T, V](first: Tpl[T, V], second: Tpl[T, V])(implicit tSum: Sum[T], vSum: Sum[V]): Tpl[T, V] =
    (tSum(first._1, second._1), tSum(first._2, second._2), vSum(first._3, second._3))

  implicit val intSum: Sum[Int] = _ + _
  implicit val strSum: Sum[String] = _ concat _

  println(mergeMsg((1, 2, "Hello"), (2, 3, "World")))
```